# Pi ethernet thrashing at boot, re-seat cable fixes it

Tags: ethernet, pi-5

got my pi 5 running and seems to work fine except for this odd problem.

Pi is running, plug in ethernet, works fine.

When I reboot the pi, the ethernet cannot properly connect; it thrashes between almost connecting and straight disconnecting. Unplugging the ethernet cable, waiting for software to register (see full disconnected status in top bar), and plugging it back in results in a stable connection.

Anyone know of a fix? Seems like an odd issue, bug, or potential defect with the new hardware.

Comment: It does seem odd...  have you tried a different patch cable?

Comment: Yes I have, also no physical movement between restarts

Comment: If it were mine, I'd contact my supplier for a return/refund.

Comment: Circling back, seems to be a strange intermittent issue when both ethernet wall ports are used at the same time, not just a pi issue either by the looks of it